# Wanted: working Bose-Hibbard Sort implementation preferably in C-like language

Tags: algorithm, sorting, algol

Please point me to code for a working Bose-Hibbard Sort implementation, preferably in a C-like language.

I'm trying to implement the algorithm in C#, but I don't have a copy of the algorithm. The only sample I have is a Fortran implementation that is a "free translation" of Hibbard's original Algol version (from 'A simple sorting algorithm' Journal of the ACM vol 10 (1963) p142-50 — which I don't have either). The Fortran version appears to be buggy (it does exactly 1 compare and ends up exiting if they are already sorted) so my primary focus is to get a working version to study.

Comment: If you are at a university, its electronic library subscription probably contains the original Hibbard article.

Comment: @thkala I'm not, unfortunately.

Comment: @Handcraftsman: What's this algorithm's claim to fame - does it have a particular strong point compared to current mainstream sorting algorithms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a scanned PDF of the [original article](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321164) (downloaded from ACM Digital Library), OCR'd by copy'n'paste on a Mac, and then manually cleaned up (quite a lot):

```
procedure ternary sort (a, n); array a; integer n; begin integer j, L;
integer array x, y[0: log2(n-1)] ; integer procedure sum(w); array w;
begin integer j, s; s := 0; for j:= 0 step 1 until L do s := s+w[j]×2↑j; sum := s
end; procedure compare; begin real w;
if a[sum(x)] > a[sum(y)] then begin w := a[sum(x)]; a[sum(x)] := a[sum(y)];
a[sum(y)] := w end end;
L := entier log2(n-1); for j := 0 step 1 until L do begin x[j] := 0;
y[j] := if j = 0 then 1 else 0 end;
A: compare; j := 0;
C: go to if x[j] = y[j] = 0 then zero else if x[j] = y[j] = 1 then one else
if x[j] = 0 then first two else two;
zero: x[j] := y[j] := 1; if sum(y) ≤ n-1 then go to A;
one: y[j] := 0; go to A;
two: x[j] := 0; j := j+1; go to C;
first two: x[j] := y[j] := 0; if j = L then go to exit; j := j+1;
if y[j] = 1 then go to D; x[j] := y[j] := 1; if sum(y) > n-1 then
go to first two; if sum(y) < n-1 then j := 0;
D: x[j] := 0; y[j] := 1; go to A;
exit: end
```

In the original, the 'log2' functions are set as 'log<sub>2</sub>'.  Line breaks as in the original.  This predates the 'structured programming' revolution - now you can see why structured programming is a good idea.  It also predates careful, clear code layout.  It is interesting seeing 'two word' labels and procedure names.  (In the [Revised Report for Algol-60](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=366193.366201&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=2778014&CFTOKEN=53440748) (PDF, or [HTML](http://www.masswerk.at/algol60/report.htm)), it says: *Typographical features such as blank space or change to a new line have no significance in the reference language. They may, however, be used freely for facilitating reading.*  This means that what appears to be 'two words' in modern computer languages is just one word in Algol-60; searching with Google shows that the keywords were differentiated from variables etc by being underlined or printed in bold or enclosed in quotes of some sort.  The language also used a number of symbols not normally found on keyboards; three examples in this program are '×', '↑', and '≤'.)

With the nested procedures, you'd need quite a lot of 'free translating' to code this in Fortran.

Here it is re-formatted - it is perhaps a little easier to see what the code is; the plethora of 'go to' statements does not make it easier to understand.  Now you can see why Dijkstra wrote 'GOTO Considered Harmful'.

```
procedure ternary sort (a, n); array a; integer n; 
begin
    integer j, L;
    integer array x, y[0: log2(n-1)]; 
    integer procedure sum(w); array w;
    begin
        integer j, s; 
        s := 0; 
        for j:= 0 step 1 until L do s := s+w[j]×2↑j; 
        sum := s
    end;
    procedure compare;
    begin
        real w;
        if a[sum(x)] > a[sum(y)] then
        begin
            w := a[sum(x)]; 
            a[sum(x)] := a[sum(y)];
            a[sum(y)] := w 
        end 
    end;
    L := entier log2(n-1);
    for j := 0 step 1 until L do
    begin
        x[j] := 0;
        y[j] := if j = 0 then 1 else 0
    end;
A:  compare; j := 0;
C:  go to if x[j] = y[j] = 0 then zero
          else if x[j] = y[j] = 1 then one
          else if x[j] = 0 then first two 
          else two;
zero:
    x[j] := y[j] := 1;
    if sum(y) ≤ n-1 then go to A;
one:
    y[j] := 0; 
    go to A;
two:
    x[j] := 0; 
    j := j+1; 
    go to C;
first two:
    x[j] := y[j] := 0;
    if j = L then go to exit; 
    j := j+1;
    if y[j] = 1 then go to D; 
    x[j] := y[j] := 1; 
    if sum(y) > n-1 then go to first two; 
    if sum(y) < n-1 then j := 0;
D:  x[j] := 0;
    y[j] := 1; 
    go to A;
exit:
end
```

Comment: +1 for the effort of OCR and cleanup.  Now if we could only untangle the nested procedures and computed gotos.

Comment: on line 26, y[j] := if i = 0 then 1 else 0 should be y[j] := if j = 0 then 1 else 0 as no variable i is defined

Comment: on line 34, z[j] should be x[j] as no array z is defined

Comment: @Handcraftsman: Fixed both those - the x in the original was fairly consistently confused with z by the OCR (but, on the whole, I was staggered at how well the OCR did given the appalling orginal).

Comment: with the corrections and some twiddling I was able to get this one working. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, this is what people did before bitwise operators. x[] and y[] are  just arrays of 1's and 0's representing (in expanded binary) two indices into array 'a'; "compare" just swaps these two elements if they are out of order; sum(x) [ or sum(y)] turns the 1's and 0's into an integer. And all the mess at the end is a method of sequencing the bits in x and y in order to get all the required pairs of elements.. So much of this code is not really part of the sort, but just overhead due to the language not allowing you to just work with bits.

Comment: What is the up-arrow operator? And it the "cross" operator what I think it is, multiplication?

Comment: Up arrow was for exponentiation; cross was indeed multiply.